# Adjust iframe by div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I"m adding content in from another website via an iframe in wordpress. I need to adjust the size of the iframe on my website, according to the size of a container div on the website in the iframe. Is it possible for javascript to access another website, and pull the height of a certain div so I can adjust the iframe accordingly??

Comment: why not create a div as a wrapper, set it to whatever size then set the iframe to 100%?

Comment: Thats actually what I'm doing, but i can't show the whole website, so I positioned the iframe in a certain position within the wrapper div.